# Take screenshot with embedded hyperlinks

Tags: windows, screenshot, hyperlink

I have a webpage with hyperlinks on it and would like to take screenshot of it with hyperlink support. That is, from the image I should be able to open those links.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: its impossible to click links aka "text" in screenshots/images esp. jpeg/.png./gif, that's why negative votes.

Comment: No, not in the way you describe. Taking a screen shot is a picture. You can't add this into common picture formats (or any that I know of). The only option may be, save to PDF, and then manually add the links back in (maybe with transparent boxes so it appears as if the text is clickable).

Comment: @Davinder: PDF is basically exactly that, though. Also **negative votes aren't negative answers** – downvoting is meant for posts that aren't _worthy_ of an answer.

Comment: @grawity right,but generally speaking, screenshot word is taken as a image format, especially when OP said "that is, from the _image_ I should...", & yes, you are right, negative votes mean people think this is not worthy of an answer.

Comment: @Davinder: Then why are you downvoting just because you don't _have_ an answer? You're already answering "no, it's impossible", so why not post it as an actual answer below?

Comment: @grawity no point of posting an "answer" which says "this post has no answer". I decided to downvote it,so that people with higher rep see it & can decide if it needs to be closed or not.

Comment: & for the record raja & @grawity, I downvoted it only now..

Answer (score 1):

Adobe Acrobat Pro also has a [Chrome Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/adobe-acrobat/efaidnbmnnnibpcajpcglclefindmkaj/related?hl=en) that allows you to save webpage as pdf with links (directions from [Adobe](https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/kb/acrobat-pro-chrome-extension.html)):

1. Open a web page in a new Chrome tab or refresh any other existing tab which has a web page loaded. The extension is enabled once the web page is completely downloaded.
2. Click the Adobe Acrobat icon displayed in the upper-right corner of the Chrome toolbar, and then choose Convert webpage to PDF.
3. Provide the file name in the Save As dialog box, and then click Save.
4. The web page is converted to PDF, and then the PDF opens in Acrobat.

BUT I believe you have to have a paid/PRO version of Acrobat, otherwise the extension has a different set of buttons which don't include pdfing a website. Even then, testing this with some coworkers, some of us were able to see the "good buttons" that include converting to PDF and some were not.

Answer (score 0):

Easy. First download the Fireshot extension for Chromecast or Firefox browser and check the Settings that it is activated (on) You will then see a large ´S´ in a blue box at the top right of your screen. Clicking this icon will give you many screen copy options. When you have selected the screen page you wish to copy, select the option saying Capture browser window and save as PDF. Click the screen once and it will start to copy and scroll to the bottom. You now have a .pdf page containing live links. NOTE. You have to register as a member. or each time you click one of the links it will otherwise take a while to display, clicking a second link. FireShot is the ONLY screen capture utility I have found to catch links.